# XAML OpenFileDialog(), missing namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro, openfiledialog

I recently started doing some WPF windows 8.1 apps and now I searched for a open file dialog. Some information is available at Microsoft and some blogs but the results are not that great.

Tried these lines:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

// Show open file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process open file dialog box results
if (result == true)
{
    // Open document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

This should work greatly as there are way more examples like this one, unfortunately not in my case because of the missing assembly reference.. It does not know Win32 in the Microsoft using.

If in any way someone can clear this out to me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just in case you are talking about a Windows Store App: that's not WPF, but [Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br211377.aspx). It has many things in common with WPF, but is actually a different framework. Here you are perhaps looking for the [FileOpenPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx) class.

Comment: Hey thanks! Sorry for the late reaction, figured the difference out myself in the last couple of weeks.